# as3 air mobile app multiple font textures

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an app I am working on which requires textfields, inputs etc.

I have created a texture atlas of the font I would like to use using GlyphDesigner and they work great.

I have created the XML and PNG files and set the font size to 20. When using it in the app it works great. I now however require a larger version of the font (60) and wondering what the best procedure would be to have multiple sized fonts on the same screen.

I tried creating another set of XML and PNG's and texture however the second declaration is being ignored. All variables have different names but the smaller font is always being called instead of the larger one. If I use the larger font texture and reduce the size it outputs fuzzy.

If I use a completely different font it works great but I would like to use the same font, just a different size.

Happy to share code if required.

Thanks

Comment: have you registered the second set and given it a different name?

Comment: yep, all have unique names.

Comment: please post your code that embeds the bitmap fonts and displays the 2 different sized textfields.